# Voltage difference between grounds

Tags: dc, ground-loop

I built the following circuit on a breadboard[image]

There are two power sources involved in the circuit, one for the Arduino (5V) and the other is the battery (3.5V) and all the components share a common ground. However I am measuring a voltage difference across different ground points. E.g. between the ground of the battery and one of the ground rail of the breadboard there is voltage difference of 0.2V and between the battery ground and the other ground rail is 0.07V.

I suppose the difference in voltage could be due to breadboard resistance but since all the grounds are connected shouldn't the voltage difference be 0? How can I make it zero?

Comment: you cannot make it zero ... connect all grounds at one point ... high current devices will still exhibit a measurable voltage drop between the grounding point and the device, but they will not affect the low current devices as much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that the grounds on your boards have a very small but non-zero impedance between them, say 0.1 ohms. Your circuit has a very high current loop of about 1 amp when the MOSFET is on, so that 1A will develop a 0.2V across the 0.1 ohm ground path. The other 0.1 ohm path to the Arduino will have relatively little current so its drop would be much smaller.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explaining it on the circuit diagram

Comment: Resistance would have to be 0.2 ohm to generate 0.2V of course.